# How to select all components of the form "*.XX" in a character vector

Tags: regex, r

I have a basic problem with R, but I cannot find a solution to it.
Let

```
v <- c( "A.BC", "R.BC", "A.AB", "R.AB", "C.BC", "S.BC")
```

be a character vector. I would like to select all components of the form  "*.BC", arriving at

```
result <- c( "A.BC", "R.BC",  "C.BC", "S.BC")
```

The use of `v=="*.BC"` in the code produces nothing meaningful.
Do you know who to correctly translate the symbol `"*.BC"` in R code?

I thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with `grep`:

```
> grep("\\.BC$", v, value = TRUE)
[1] "A.BC" "R.BC" "C.BC" "S.BC"
```

where `"\\."` indicates `"."` and `"$"` indicates the end of the string.